# recompile vim with +python

Tags: python, vim, omnicomplete

When I try to use omnicomplete in a .py file vim says that I need to compile vim with +python support. I already have a bunch of plugins downloaded in my vimfiles with pathogen so how do I recompile vim 7.3 with +python support without losing my settings? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settings won't be lost if you recompile `vim`: recompilation will simply create a new `vim` executable. If you are using a common Linux distribution, though, you might not need to compile anything: Archlinux, for example, bundles "vim compiled with +python" in the gvim package. Your distro might do something similar.